# How to access a style inside user control in UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp, user-controls, styles, uwp-xaml

I have a user control like this:

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <HyperlinkButton Grid.Row="0" />

        <TextBlock Name="textblock" Grid.Row="1"
                   Text="{Binding dailyText, ElementName=userControl}">

        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Nevertheless, I don't know, how can I set a style from mainwindow to user control? I have solved the problem to access to other properties like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyContent", typeof(object), typeof(Day), null);
public object MyContent
{
    get { return (object)GetValue(MyContentProperty ); }
    set { SetValue(MyContentProperty , value); }
}
```

And then

```
<local:Day MyContent="Hello World" />
```

However, it doesn't work the style. There is no change in the sytle.

Thank you.

---

(Modification)

Below is a mainWindow part.

```html
<Page.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Name="MyTextBlockStyle">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
            <Setter Property="SelectionHighlightColor" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10"/>
        </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<local:Day MyStyle="{StaticResource MyTextBlockStyle}">
```

Behind-code part in userControl

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyStyleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyStyle", typeof(Style), typeof(Day), null);
    public Style MyStyle
    {
        get { return (Style)GetValue(MyStyleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyStyleProperty, value); }
    }
```

Comment: SO is not a free code delivery website. What have you tried you need to explain with code? please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for correcting my mistake. Does this edit fit your intention?

Comment: Show the 'style in MainWindow' part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `PropertyMetadata` to initialise and set `Style` to your `TextBlock`. Like,

```
public Style MyStyle
{
    get { return (Style)GetValue(MyStyleProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MyStyleProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty MyStyleProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("MyStyle", typeof(Style), typeof(Day), 
                                new PropertyMetadata(null, OnStyleChange));

private static void OnStyleChange(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var control = d as Day;
    control.textblock.Style = (Style)e.NewValue
}
```

Comment: I was having trouble with that problem. Thank you it's working :)